# Интерактивная шкала просмотра контента

Tags: прокрутка

Друзья, как бы вы сделали интерактивную шкалу, как здесь в третьей секции? https://vyborg.me/
При скролле она уменьшается в размерах, цифры с обозначением года меняют позицию.
Предполагаю, что нужно использовать готовый плагин, но непонятно, какой выбрать. А может и без плагинов можно, вручную?

Comment: извините, но *StackOverflow* - это не площадка для философствования (быть или не быть, подключать или не подключать)